# Service snmpd restart issue

Tags: networking, network-programming, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am facing this particular error

```
/usr/sbin/snmpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/snmpd: undefined symbol: smux_listen_sd
```

when I restart the snmpd service on my computer. Whenever I do the `sudo service snmpd restart`, it gives me the error shown above.

I have tried to search this issue on web, but the suggestion which I got is that snmp libraries are on present on path `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/local/lib/`, but I could not see snmp libraries on both paths. My snmp libraries are present only on `/usr/local/lib`.

I also tried to uninstall `snmpd`, but it gave me same error. I don't want to remove `net-snmp` package as it has dependency on other modules. I am working on Ubuntu 13.10.

Could any one help me?

Comment: Can anybody comment on this..Any body ????

Comment: How did you install net-snmp? Did you install it by source at first, then by apt-get?

Comment: I installed it by source at first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relocation error.

One of the biggest advantages of package managers is that when you remove a package all that came with it gets removed. This does not happen with source installs.

Basically you should remove everything netsnmp related and then reinstall the package with apt:

- remove net-snmp with apt-get. Use `--nodeps` if you don't want to remove the dependencies
- locate all libsnmp versions you have in your system with `find /usr/ -name libnetsnmp*` and delete them.
- alternatively, if you still have the source install folder on disk, you could try running `sudo make uninstall` in the same folder where you run `sudo make install`. This is cleaner but doesn't always work.
- lastly install net-snmp with apt-get once again

You should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer step by step [source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/apt-get-install-snmpd-gives-error-undefined-symbol-boot_dynaloader-729019/):

> I solve this problem
>
> apt-get remove --purge snmpd cd /usr/local/lib/ rm libnetsnmp*
>
> apt-get install snmpd
>
> verify if this service is open netstat -anup
>
> test this : snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost
>
> Is good !!!